# Use jQuery to post data to php file

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am making a search engine.I want to post the data from jquery to php.

Here is my code of jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 && $('#textfield').val()) {
        $.post("search_result.php",
        {
          wording: $('#textfield').val()              
        }, function() {
        window.location = "search_result.php";        
        }
        );
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is my code of php to get the wording:

```
<?php include('../include/common_top.php');


        $key_word = $_POST["wording"];
        var_dump($key_word);
?>
```

But what I get is a null value.Please help.

Comment: If you run `$('#textfield').val()` in the console, what do you see?

Comment: I see the wording that I have typed.

Comment: in the php page can you check `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: It is an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't redirect to the PHP script. That runs it a second time, but this time with no POST parameters.

The output of the PHP script from the AJAX request will be the argument to the callback function, you can display it from there.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 && $('#textfield').val()) {
        $.post("search_result.php",
            {
              wording: $('#textfield').val()              
            }, function(result) {
                $("#somediv").text(result);   
            }
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you mean I should use the post function to change the div content of the php file?

Comment: Yes. The point of using AJAX is so that you don't reload the page.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to open a new php page not changing the div content?

Comment: You could just submit the form.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciate your solution.